# C++ define a function iff another function does not exist

Tags: c++, swap, template-meta-programming, sfinae

In versions of C++11 and above, you can use the following pattern to perform member detection in a simple way:

```
template <typename MyClass>
auto swap(MyClass &lhs, MyClass &rhs) -> decltype (lhs.swap(rhs), void())
{
    std::cout << "Swapping LHS with RHS by calling the member function!\n";
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}
```

That is, by using the late return type, we're allowed to use the names `lhs` and `rhs` in `decltype`, and multiple expressions in `decltype` can be chained by using the comma operator. `decltype` will fail to typecheck if the included expressions are not valid, but this will not raise a compiler error but instead trigger SFINAE, as it is encountered during type resolution.

Above code works perfect, as long as:

- `MyClass` is not a CRDT-child-class of our current class, as in this case because of inheritance, the current class is compiled first and therefore does not yet have access to what members are defined in the child class.
- This cannot be used to do it the other way around: Only define a function implementation if another function does *not* exist.

And this is what this question is about:

**How can a(n overloaded template) function be only get defined if another member function does *not* exist?**

Above example, for instance, defines a `swap(lhs, rhs)` that wraps a `lhs.swap(rhs)` function. However, in cases where a `lhs.swap(rhs)` does not exist, I want to create an alternative variant that, instead of calling `lhs.swap(rhs)`, calls `std::swap(lhs, rhs)`.

Note that I do not want to use ADL lookup here, because that's the point: The idea is to give a `swap(lhs, rhs)` function to any class that only (possibly) has a `lhs.swap(rhs)` function defined.

**How can this be done?**

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) for that.

Here's an example. For simplicity, I use a different formulation of the same method for detecting existence of a member, and wrap it in a trait `has_member_swap`.

```
template <typename... T> struct make_void { typedef void type; };
template <typename... T> using void_t = typename make_void<T...>::type;

template <typename, typename, typename = void>
struct has_member_swap : std::false_type { };
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct has_member_swap<T1, T2,
  void_t<decltype( std::declval<T1&>().swap(std::declval<T2&>()) )>
> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<has_member_swap<T,T>::value> swap(T& lhs, T& rhs) {
  lhs.swap(rhs);
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!has_member_swap<T,T>::value> swap(T& lhs, T& rhs) {
  std::swap(lhs,rhs);
}
```

[`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) is available since c++17.